# Any analytical math solver as preprocessor?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, preprocessor, symbolic-math

Solving (system of) equations by hand can be error prone. I waisted a lot of time in my life looking for bugs on my piece of paper in my derivation. Having experienced Maple, and its ability to `solve` equations and `rsolve` recursive equations, I was wondering if there is any tool out there that preprocesses code to solve equations analytically for a certain set of variables, and output the solution in analytical form, such that in the next step, the compiler compiles the solution.

I wrote this toy example (completely made up, incorrect and under-constrained), of what I think this might look like, in C++:

```cpp
tuple<3> example_function(double y, double z, double alpha) {
    // define variables
    $real x, p0, gamma; // << unknowns
    $real y, z, alpha;  // << givens

    // define equations
    $eq rule1 = x*x / p0^gamma == 1;
    $eq rule2 = gamma^2 + p0^2 == 1;

    // instruct the preprocessor to solve it
    $prog pr = solve {rule1, rule2}
               for   {x, p0, gamma}
               assuming (positive x,
                         positive z,
                         positive gamma);

    // define output variables to store the results in
    double x, p0, gamma;

    // now let the preprocessor output the solved equations
    $exec pr;

    return tuple<3>({x, p0, gamma});
}
```

The dollar ($) signs indicate the math language to be preprocessed.
This could for example be preprocessed to something like:

```cpp
tuple<3> example_function(double y, double z, double alpha) {
    double x, p0, gamma;
    x = std::pow(y, -z) / (alpha - 1.0);
    p0 = x / alpha;
    gamma = alpha * alpha;

    return tuple<3>({x, p0, gamma});
}
```

Of course, the preprocessor would know this language is C++ such that it can use keywords like `double` and use the `std::` math functions.

Does anything like this exist? If not, any reason for this and what do you think about this idea?

Comment: Those rules might not have a closed form solution - what happens (or should happen) then?

Comment: Nobody solves systems of equations by hand once there are more than three.  That's what linear algebra is for.  "Error prone"?  Try "impossible".  Meaningful problems have millions of degrees of freedom.  This idea makes no sense.

Comment: Why this job should be done by a pre-processor? What is the benefit comparing to giving this task to some specialized math library? You must have huge benefits to offset huge costs of building such a complicated monster and so far you provided none. And this is the reason why such a tool has not been built.

Comment: @duffymo: What are you talking about? *Linear* algebra is only... linear. Of course I can invert a matrix. I'm talking about arbitrary systems with exp, log, divisions, multiplications, summations. I simply want to describe the things I want the solution to comply to. The compiler-preprocessor can then insert the closed form solutions. If you don't understand why this is useful, you probably didn't try to program anything engineering / physics related. I'd say: have a look at Maple.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Simply tell the user its can't solve that. For many cases simple enough (cfr Maple), this could be a huge win.

Comment: @SergGr: I don't want the runtime overhead of solving the problem. And of course I don't want the extra dependencies.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, 1) I see no difference between dependency on a pre-processor and on a library 2) as to "runtime overhead" this almost never can be achieved. Not having "runtime overhead" means your system of equations must have a) a closed form solution and b) it must be of such a form that it is significantly faster to calculate it than to solve the system numerically from the scratch. Even requiring a closed form solution rules out most of the classes of equations. Requiring it to be fast rules out almost everything else (even just system of linear equations)

Comment: @SergGr: I must be explaining terribly I suppose... **Current workflow**: write down equations on paper, solve them analytically by hand, enter the solutions back into my source file. (Alternative current approach: open Maple, enter equations, let maple solve it, copy result error-prone back to source file.) **What I want**: write equations in my source file, let preprocessor solve the equations, so that I don't have to make error-prone calculations on paper and copy the formula's error prone from my paper to the source file.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, what I say is that searching for such a preprocessor as an alternative is just attempt to look for a wrong thing. If your formula has closed form solution - use something like Maple (and I don't see why copying it back should be that error prone). And if it has none - no pre-processor can help you. I understand what you want but the fact that you want it is not enough for a thing to exist. For example, it should be economically feasible and what I'm trying to say is that what you want is not and that's why it doesn't exist.

Comment: About economics... Maple is 2990 USD today. I have free access because I am a university student, but Maple is definitely not an economical solution. Not to mention the gigabytes of space it takes. WolframAlpha would do the trick for free I guess.

Comment: As far as Im aware there is no product that does what you describe. But there is a product that does what you want: to avoid error-prone manual transcription of equations to code. Take a look at Matlab and Simulink. You can let Matlab solve equations for you and then set up simulink to compile it to C

Comment: I think this is a great question, and I am unsure why commenters get caught up in the idea of a 'preprocessor' that does not exist. I see the solution to this as a 'preprocessing' in the form of a process that determines the closed form solution, if it exists, and writes code (and generates test cases?) for it.
Maybe that is what simulink does? IDK.

Comment: I linked your question to this issue in [sympy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14614)